Download file in the ubuntu terminal
I have a question. My situation is that I host my website on a ubuntu Server and I have clone my github reposentory to it. I could find my file by using the cd command but now the question, is it possable to download this file that i could make a local backup?
ps: its not the same file like on github because this file change by using my website.
I hope you could help :D
thanks

have  a look at the wget command, Without more details about what you want it will be difficult to say mpre about it

I am not sure I understand your question. Can you please edit your question with more details?

If this file is in repo and was altered on the server why you just don't create new branch and push it to the repo?
You probably still can download the file with wget or curl.
